# Data is not inserted in mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to change password in mysql Db. Here is userChangePassword.php file

```
<?php
require_once '../include/db_operations.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $db = new DbOperations();
        if ($db->changePassword($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Change Password Successfully";

            // go to dboperation

        } else {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = "Password not changed";
        }
    } else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Fill all the feilds";
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

This file is db_Operations.php contain function of changing password in database
Method is working fine but password is not changed in database but message is displayed "successfully changed password"

```
<?php
class DbOperations
{
    private $con;
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/db_connected.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

    public function userLogin($username, $pass)
    {
        $password = $pass;
        $stm = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM student WHERE username = ? AND password = ? ");
        $stm->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $stm->execute();
        $stm->store_result();
        return $stm->num_rows > 0;
    }

    public function getUserByUserName($username)
    {
        $stm = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM student WHERE username = ?");
        $stm->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stm->execute();
        return $stm->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }

    /*For insertion*/
    public function createUser($username, $pass, $email)
    {
        $password = $pass;
        $stm = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
        $stm->bind_param("sss", $username, $password, $email);
        if ($stm->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // for change password

    public function changePassword($username, $pass)
    {
        $password = $pass;
        $stm = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE student SET password = ? WHERE username = ? ;");
        $stm->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        if ($stm->execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
{"error":false,"message":"Change Password Successfully"}
```

All other method and queries are fine only changedPassword() method is not performing well.

These are the parameters used in database:

[image]

Comment: **this question** has nothing to do with android

Comment: there is semi-colon in your update remove it

Comment: Basically i am developing an android application using mysql db this is php script for login and registering user and change password method. But change password method is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in order of params binded in

```
$stm->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
```

It means that first `?` will be replaced with `$username` and second `?` with `$password`. Sure, it is not what you need. So, the solution is:

```
$stm->bind_param("ss", $password, $username);
```

As a sidenote: **never** store plain passwords in a database. Related topic [here](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).